# Illegal reference to non-static member... typedef?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, non-static

Why do I get

> Error C2597: Illegal reference to non-static member `'derived<<unnamed-symbol>>::T'`

when I try to compile this code in Visual C++ 2010 x64? (It seems fine on x86... which one is correct?)

```
struct base { typedef int T; };

template<class>
struct derived : base
{
    using base::T;
    derived(T = T()) { }
};

int main()
{
    derived<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fail to reproduce the problem with x64 MSVC 11.0

Comment: I'm getting the same error on VS2010 x86 also. Seems the problem is the `T()` default value. If you change the instantiation to `derived<int>(0);` it compiles. No idea what the hiccup is though.

Comment: Shouldnt that be `template<typename T>`  or `template<class T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Praetorian's comment mentions, the problem is with the `T()` default value. Based on the error details, `using base::T` apparently confuses the compiler into searching for `T()` as a call to non-static member function of `base` rather than the construction of an instance of type `T`.

Here's an interesting fix that works in MSVC 2005 x86 (I haven't tried any other compiler). Note that `T()` is preserved. This either disambiguates `using base::T` or just forces `T` to reference the inherited type and not the `using` one (which are apparently not the same thing to the compiler).

```
//...
template<class>
struct derived : base
{
    using base::T;
    derived(T = static_cast<T>( T() )) { } //No error
};
//...
```

---

*Edit:* Try changing `base` to this and see what error messages you get:

```
struct base { struct T{T(){}}; };
```

I get the original `C2597`, but also this:

> error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from '' to 'base::T'
>   No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

I don't know what the compiler means by `''` there, but it's probably a similar problem with the original definition of `base`. This compiles fine if I remove the `using base::T;` line.

Comment: Whoa that's... weird. :) +1 nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `using base::T`? Types that defined in base class will be automatically avaiable in derived class.

```
struct base { typedef int T; };
template< class X >
struct derived : base {};
derived<int>::T v = 0;  // this is OK in C++
```

Comment: I was using `base::T` because the original code was a lot more complicated (templates, etc.) and the compiler complained it couldn't find `T` if I didn't give it the `using` hint.

Comment: So if it is you can `typedef` it, like all implementations of STL. use `typedef base::T T` and it should work with all compilers!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead (should be self explanatory):

```
template<class T>
struct derived : base
{
    derived(T = T()) { }
};
```